# How to consume WCF Data Service from Controller (MVC5, EF6, WCF 5.6)

Tags: .net, wcf, entity-framework

I followed the steps from the "Getting Started" of the microsoft site ([Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728278%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

and all went well until I tried this step in the Controller:

```
private Uri svcUri = new Uri("~/Services/ChannelWCF.svc");

context = new ChannelEntities(svcUri);
```

ChannelEntities does not recognize the param svcUri, the dbcontext that was generated automatically have no methods with a single argument...

Here goes my WCF Data Service:

```
    public class ChannelWCF : EntityFrameworkDataService<ChannelEntities>
    {

       // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
       public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
       {
          config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("QuotaSet", EntitySetRights.All);
          config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
          config.UseVerboseErrors = true;           
      }
}
```

I'm able to see it in the web browser (localhost:12345/ChannelWCF.svc) and I also can consume the service directly with json in the view.

Could somebody show me the light? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly add web service in **Service Referance**. Just right click on **References** select **Add Service Reference**.

See this link for more details :

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/krishnasarala/accessing-wcf-service-in-Asp-Net-mvc-application/